# Product Images of mobile responsive site

Tags: image, magento, magento-1.8, catalog

Im using magento 1.8.10. My website is also mobile responsive site. Images of the products is showing very large on the lending page and if anyone clicks on the products then images showing small when people using my site on mobile.

Anyone can help that how to show perfect images of every prodcuts ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its simple just use

```
<?php 

    echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')
        ->constrainOnly(false)
        ->keepAspectRatio(true)
        ->keepFrame(true)
        ->resize(160, 210);

?>
```

or whatever size you want to give you can mention in resize

Comment: pleasure always mine :)